# How to transfer data to the mysql table?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

How to transfere data from a Mysql table or from DataTables to another Mysql table in Laravel?

This second part of code shows that the data is deleted from the first table after transfer complete. The first part is my question, it should be in the same function and event.

View

```
$(document).on('click', '#Confirm', function(){
    var table = $('#panier_table').DataTable();
    var i = 2;    
    var colId = table.column( 0 ).index();

    var id = [];
    if(confirm("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir confirmer cette commande?"))
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < table.data().count(); i++)
        {
            var rowId = table.row( i ).index();
            console.log( table.cells({ row: rowId, column: colId }).data()[0] );
            id.push(table.cells({ row: rowId, column: colId }).data()[0]);
        }                            
        if(id.length > 0)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{ route('ajaxdata.commande')}}",
                method:"get",
                data:{id:id},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                    $('#panier_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
function Commande(Request $request)
{
    $pn = $request->input('id');
    $pdr = Panier::whereIn('id', $pn);
    if($pdr->delete())
    {
        echo 'Commande Confirmée';
    }
}
```

Here is the outcome:

[image]

Comment: Since you have you $pdr, you can store this data in the new table through its model

Comment: Do you try to slove this problem like Laradocs shows? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

Comment: @Jasper Helmich, can you show me the code to do this?

Comment: Why would you use client side js in transferring data between MySQL tables?

Comment: @Shadow the client only send his ID but the data transfer is server side in the same function `Commande` like the delete.

Answer (score 1):

So you now have this,

```
function Commande(Request $request)
{
    $pn = $request->input('id');
    $pdr = Panier::whereIn('id', $pn);
    if($pdr->delete())
    {
       echo 'Commande Confirmée';
    }
}
```

Since you have your data in $pdr on this line

```
 $pdr = Panier::whereIn('id', $pn);
```

With that data you could store it in a different table let say i want to transfer it to the users table i could try the following

```
 User::create([
    'name' => $pdr->name,
    'email' => $pdr->email,
 ])
```

Assign what data you want connected to each column

So your final function will look a bit like this

```
function Commande(Request $request)
{
    $pn = $request->input('id');
    $pdr = Panier::whereIn('id', $pn);

    $user = User::create([
       'name' => $pdr->name,
       'email' => $pdr->email,
    ])
    if($user){
       if($pdr->delete())
       {
          echo 'Commande Confirmée';
       }        
    }

}
```

Change User to a model of your liking

Comment: I got this: 
`"Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$ID_User"` at line: `'ID_User' => $pdr->ID_User,`

Answer (score 0):

This is working but i must insert the same number of attributes that are in the first table or i get this error:

```
"SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 (SQL: INSERT into Commandes (ID_User, ID_Pi ▶"
```

I just need 3 attributes `(ID_User, ID_Piece, QTE)`:

```
function Commande(Request $request)
{
    $pn = $request->input('id');
    $pdr = Panier::whereIn('id', $pn);

    $bindings = $pdr->getBindings();
    $insertQuery = 'INSERT into Commandes (id, ID_Ligne, ID_Piece, ID_User, Piece, QTE, created_at, updated_at) '
    . $pdr->toSql();

    \DB::insert($insertQuery, $bindings);

       if($pdr->delete())
       {
          echo 'Commande Confirmée';
       }            

}
```

Comment: @JasperHelmich i tried your answer look at comment.

Comment: I posted a screenshot to your answer, refresh the page.

Comment: Which modal name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188417/discussion-between-jasper-helmich-and-sami).